# How to restore xml state after a method is called in android

Tags: java, android, database, firebase

Code:

```
 private void updateQuestion() {
    mDatabaseReference.child("Users").child(RecieversId).child("Quiz").child("Question" + mQuestionNumber).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            String question = dataSnapshot.child("Question").getValue().toString();
            answer = dataSnapshot.child("Answer").getValue().toString();
            option1 = dataSnapshot.child("Option1").getValue().toString();
            option2 = dataSnapshot.child("Option2").getValue().toString();
            option3 = dataSnapshot.child("Option3").getValue().toString();
            option4 = dataSnapshot.child("Option4").getValue().toString();
            que.setText(question);
            opt1.setText(option1);
            opt2.setText(option2);
            opt3.setText(option3);
            opt4.setText(option4);
        }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        }
    });

    opt1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mQuestionNumber++;
            updateQuestion();
            qn.setText("Quesion : " + mQuestionNumber);
            if (option1.equals(answer)) {
                opt1.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
                mScore++;
                sco.setText("Score : " + mScore);
                updateQuestion();
            } else
                opt1.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
            sco.setText("Score : " + mScore);
            updateQuestion();
        }
    });
    opt2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mQuestionNumber++;
            updateQuestion();
            qn.setText("Quesion : " + mQuestionNumber);
            if (option2.equals(answer)) {
                opt2.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
                mScore++;
                sco.setText("Score : " + mScore);
                updateQuestion();
            } else
                opt2.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
            sco.setText("Score : " + mScore);
            updateQuestion();
        }
    });
    opt3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mQuestionNumber++;
            qn.setText("Quesion : " + mQuestionNumber);
            if (option3.equals(answer)) {
                opt3.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
                mScore++;
                sco.setText("Score : " + mScore);
                updateQuestion();
            } else
                opt3.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
            sco.setText("Score : " + mScore);
            updateQuestion();
        }
    });
    opt4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mQuestionNumber++;
            qn.setText("Quesion : " + mQuestionNumber);
            if (option4.equals(answer)) {
                opt4.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
                mScore++;
                sco.setText("Score : " + mScore);
                updateQuestion();
            } else
                opt4.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
            sco.setText("Score : " + mScore);
            updateQuestion();

        }
    });
    }
 }
```

Just trying to make a quiz application... updatequestion is called after everybutton click(after user chooses answer)... the button turns green if its correct and red if its wrong... but that color stays even after going to the next question... how do i make it to get the color which is mentioned in the xml file... thats the default button color

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way would be to add this to your `onDataChanged()` method:

```
opt1.setBackgroundColor(<default_color_reference>);
opt2.setBackgroundColor(<default_color_reference>);
opt3.setBackgroundColor(<default_color_reference>);
opt4.setBackgroundColor(<default_color_reference>);
```

Right after you set the text. And make sure `<default_color_reference>` matches the original background color you desire, assuming you specifically set that in your XML file.

Comment: Sorry, I formatted that wrong. I mean that "Color.DEFAULT" should match to a color resource file that is set to the buttons that the XML references. Not exactly copying and pasting my answer. "Color.TRANSPARENT" works too if the color isn't something specific that is already set. (For instance, maybe the XML background is set to a specific set of gray or pale blue or something)

Answer (score 2):

inside update question, reset the color of all textview because you are reusing those textviews and state of textviews will remain the same so use

```
mDatabaseReference.child("Users").child(RecieversId).child("Quiz").child("Question" + mQuestionNumber).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            String question = dataSnapshot.child("Question").getValue().toString();
            answer = dataSnapshot.child("Answer").getValue().toString();
            option1 = dataSnapshot.child("Option1").getValue().toString();
            option2 = dataSnapshot.child("Option2").getValue().toString();
            option3 = dataSnapshot.child("Option3").getValue().toString();
            option4 = dataSnapshot.child("Option4").getValue().toString(); 
            //-------------------
            opt1.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
            opt2.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
            opt3.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
            opt4.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
            //-------------------
            que.setText(question);
            opt1.setText(option1);
            opt2.setText(option2);
            opt3.setText(option3);
            opt4.setText(option4);               
        }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        }
    });
```